# Sharepoint out of the box capabilities

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am planning to build a case management system from scratch, The system will incorporate a workflow. Cases will contain activities to be performed by different people inside and outside the company within a specified window of time.

Does SharePoint support a configurable workflow engine that I might use for this project?

Comment: You  may want to rename the subject of this post to something that includes your workflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Workflow is one of the strong parts of SharePoint. Out-of-the box you or your users can build workflows using the free SharePoint Designer. Depending on your exact requirements this may be good enough.

If you need a more advanced workflow editor then you may want to consider Nintex Workflow or K2. Alternatively you can write your own workflows in Visual Studio or buy 3rd part Workflow Actions for SharePoint Designer.

I have included some useful links below:

- [Building workflows using SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101005911033.aspx)
- [Creating workflows using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms564355.aspx)
- [3rd Part Workflow actions to embed VB or C# directly into SharePoint Designer Workflows](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). Note that I have worked on this product so consider my recommendation biased ;-)