# Is it possible to add workflow modification programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I`m interested in adding SharePoint Workflow Modification programmatically from my workflow, without using forms.

What i'm trying to achieve - I want to add Workflow modification when user uploads new document version to document library. I have OnWorkflowItemChanged and from there i'm willing to add WF Modification.

Is this possible?

To clarify some things:
I`m writing a custom Workflow in Visual Studio.

What I want is to add items to (SPWorkflowModificationCollection) SPWorkflow.Modifications object. However there is no Add method, but the designed way to add items there is by using Workflow Modification forms.

In this case, i don't want user to use [modification form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms480794.aspx), but i want to add workflow modifications (which will populate the collection AND triger OnWorkflowModified event).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by *workflow modification*. Do you want to modify the workflow itself from a workflow or just modify a document or item from a SharePoint Workflow?

Regardless, I'll give you the same answer to what was accepted as the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256492/sharepoint-out-of-the-box-capabilities/2256861#2256861).

Workflow is one of the strong parts of SharePoint. Out-of-the box you or your users can build workflows using the free SharePoint Designer. Depending on your exact requirements this may be good enough.

If you need a more advanced workflow editor then you may want to consider Nintex Workflow or K2. Alternatively you can write your own workflows in Visual Studio or buy 3rd part Workflow Actions for SharePoint Designer.

I have included some useful links below:

- [Building workflows using SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101005911033.aspx)
- [Creating workflows using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms564355.aspx)
- [3rd Part Workflow actions to embed VB or C# directly into SharePoint Designer Workflows](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). Note that I have worked on this product so consider my recommendation biased ;-)